# Why doesn't my cat seem to mind loud music despite stronger hearing?

Tags: cats, behavior, hearing

I am effectively making a colloquial assumption that my cat's hearing is better than mine but... if this truly is the case, why doesn't my cat seem to mind loud music? Surprising noises that come out of nowhere (regardless of volume) always freak him out for a second, but for some reason, he seems unbothered by the volume of consistent music. I say this specifically because there are times I have had the music on in the living room with a big stereo system and he will sit very close to it but not really need to move. I am not sure I could stand sitting that close and his ears are stronger than mine... why isn't he phased?
His hearing in other situations is excellent, so I am not sure that it would be related to any sort of deafness.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11869/do-loud-noises-damage-cats-hearing

Answer (score -1):

He could really like the music that you like because cats have senses that humans will never have and probably won't really understand the first time hearing about this, but cats can sense if we are happy, sad, mad, scared, or sick. A lot of times, cats like things that their owners like. But one thing cats really hate is water, I have only had one cat that would like to take a bath or go swimming. But back to your question here is a link to help you understand https://thecatisinthebox.com/blogs/kitty-contemplations/noises-cats-love-noises-cats-hate.

Comment: Please make sure that all relevant information is *in your post*, not at some linked site. The Internet is notorious for link rot, and each answer on SE should be able to stand alone. Links are fine for additional details, of course.